# JQuery doesn't work on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use JQuery in WordPress pages but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    $('a[href="http://domain1"]').attr("href","http://domain2");
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in console

Comment: *"JQuery doesn't work on WordPress"* Yes, it does.

Comment: Be sure you haven´t included it twice. Check your sourcecode.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar No errors in the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `jQuery` keyword instead of `$` shortcut when you put JQuery in WordPress pages..
and eliminate new line characters and unnecessary spaces as well like shown below:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('a[href="http://domain1"]').attr("href","domain2");});</script>
```

Comment: *"...and eliminate new line characters and unnecessary spaces..."* Why? How can that be even remotely necessary?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It worked perfectly only when all the newline characters are eliminated..

Comment: @user3206125: I find that very, very hard to believe. I suspect observational error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know but that was the truth,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When it comes to any theme php file, this is not necessary but when adding JQuery through the dashboard->pages. please note that this is not happening always.

Answer (score 4):

Normally jQuery is conflict with `Wordpress` since they're both using `$`, try to do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href="http://domain1"]').attr("href","http://domain2");
});
```

or put your code inside a closure:

```
(function($){
    $('a[href="http://domain1"]').attr("href","http://domain2");
})(jQuery);
```